# Using multiple Apple Developer accounts on one MacOS account?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Suppose a developer needs to use **several Apple Developer program identities (contracts)**, say ADP1 and ADP2.

Dev1 signed by developer himself, Dev2 by a third party.

May the developer set up **a single Mac OS account to use/manage both accounts** for development with Xcode? Import certificates for ADP1 and ADP2. Validate or submit apps for each account?

Or will Xcode get confused? Or would it be wise to setup a single Mac OS account for ADP1 and ADP2?

Comment: I do this regularily, and my Xcode never got confused...

Comment: @Michael Thank you, Michael. Never done that before. And before Xcode gets confused, I wondered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe personally to only one `Apple Developer Program` of each type (iOS, MAC, Safari). However, you can be part of many `Apple Developer Program`. That means that people can add you to their dev team in their own `Apple Developer Program`. I don't thinks there is a limit.

`Xcode` won't get confused : it will ask you for the team you want to use for every project.